# How do I add "&Source" to DataNavigateUrlFormatString?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, .net

Solution:

```
<asp:TemplateField SortExpression="Exp" HeaderText="text">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/SubSite/Default.aspx?reg={0}&Source={1}", Eval("Id"), Request.Url) %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Instead of:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="Name" DataNavigateUrlFields="Id"
                DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~\SubSite\Default.aspx?reg={0}"
                HeaderText="text" SortExpression="Exp" />
```

---

Greetings

I have a GridView containing some HyperLinkFields. What I am trying to do is to add the "&Source" query in the `DataNavigateUrlFormatString` when I click one of the hyperlinks.

When I do it like this: `DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~\SubSite\Default.aspx?Query={0}&Source=<% Request.Url.AbsolutePath%>"`

The URL I get is this: `http://www.website.com/SubSite/Default.aspx?Query=702&Source=<%Request.Url.AbsolutePath%>`

How do I make sure it writes the URL that I try to get through `<% Request.Url.AbsolutePath%>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~\SubSite\Default.aspx?Query={0}&Source=" +Request.Url.AbsolutePath
```

OR This:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Find the control and set the values you need
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the second suggestion then and do it in the code behind when the row databinds.